# 4.5m DisplayPort to HDMI cable does not work

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I connected my Desktop PC to a monitor via a 4.5m long DisplayPort to HDMI cable, but the monitor does not receive any input signals.

What I have tried so far:

1. I changed the cable but got same result
2. I updated the drivers to the last version of my "Intel® HD Graphics 630" card
3. I connected the same monitor with the same cable to another PC and **I got the signal**
4. I connected the same monitor and my desktop PC with a shorter DisplayPort to HDMI cable (same connection as the long cable) and **I got the signal**

This is a link of the DisplayPort to HDMI cable I bought:

https://www.secomp-international.com/en_US/_/i/11.04.5783-10/18191

Do you have any suggestion for my problem? Could be possible that the output signal of my PC port has not enough strenght?

Comment: This is a "_DisplayPort to HDMI_" cable... not a plain "_DisplayPort to DisplayPort_" cable... Which end is connected to which? Is the HDMI end at the PC or Monitor?

Comment: Is the "_shorter DISPLAYPORT cable_" also actually "_DisplayPort to HDMI_"? Is it oriented the same way? (i.e: HDMI at the Monitor in both cases)

Comment: What resolution are you trying to use?

Comment: `Note: A DisplayPort HDTV cable can only be used in one direction: the DisplayPort connector can only be used on the data source side (e. g. graphics card).` This is straight from the website, and underlines Atties comment.

Comment: Both cables (short and long) are "DisplayPort to HDMI" and I used same orientation. The DisplayPort is connected to the PC, the HDMI to the monitor. I'm trying to  use 1980x1080 resolution.

Comment: Is it definitely **1980**x1080?  that's a slightly unusual resolution (and would be higher than the cable supports), **1920**x1080 would be far more typical and is the maximum that cable supports.

Comment: I'm sorry, wrong digit. 1920x1080 is the resolution. I also tried with lover resolution but i got also no responses

Comment: This sounds like a low-quality cable. You might try a cable from another manufacturer.

Comment: Could be a low-quality cable. But I cannot explain me why this cable works when I connect it to another PC

Comment: What refresh rate are you aiming for? is it the same on both PCs?

Comment: The refresh rate is 60p Hz on both PCs

Comment: "_I cannot explain me why this cable works when I connect it to another PC_" every piece of electronics has slightly different tolerances... that other PC could drive the line harder, and the monitor could have better receive front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing the graphic card:

"NVIDIA Quadro 2000" works properly

Maybe also using an active DisplayPort to HDMI converter could be a possible solution, but I cannot try this solution at the moment.